# ¿How html pages in e-stores are generated for every product?

Tags: javascript, html, web, e-commerce, backend

in web pages like ebay and other e-stores where you can sell your stuff, ¿how are generated the individual pages of every product? Everytime someone adds a product a new html page is generated? or how does this work? i´m not asking for specific code, just an explanation or a link where i can learn this. thanks!

Comment: The content is dynamically generated by applying data to a page template.  Start with pretty much any tutorial on web development with a server-side technology.  PHP, ASP.NET, Ruby, Python, Java, etc.

Comment: Like most programming problems, there are many ways to implement this. But the overall idea is to have a database of all your products and their details, a computer that can accept queries for products then comb through the products and return some results, and lastly a front-end web-page that allows users to easily make those queries (a search) then understands how to display the returned results. In this way, you don't need to pre-construct a web page for every item. It is generated in real time when a request needs to display that item. If you start a website, look into "CMS shopping cart".